# .NET: determine DST status for a given day in the past?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, timestamp

For a given date in the past, and assuming a US timezone, how can I use C# to determine whether or not Daylight Saving Time was in active for that day?

I have a timestamp for a given day in the past (the day and time were recorded separately) that I know would not have considered DST when recording itself, and I need to turn that timestamp into the local time of day (again, assuming a given US timezone) on which it was recorded, given the day on which it was recorded.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "would not have considered DST when reocrding itself"? What exact code would it have been using?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've observed that the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` syntax does not consider DST when populating the version's Revision.  I can't speak to what code drives that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingsTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx) will do this. But, it might not be correct for the times previous to when they recently [changed the period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_Act_of_2005#Change_to_daylight_saving_time).

Answer (score 0):

There are one or two implementations of the ZoneInfo db for .NET, for example http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm (the one used by Java and Unixes)